# Método migrations entity framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

Normalmente quando trabalhamos com o entity framework, utilizamos no console as chamadas

```
add-migration migrationName
update-database
```

Gostaria de tornar isso um método, para quando chama-lo, ele seja executado.

Motivo: estou implementando multitenancy em meu banco, irei separar meus clientes por schema.
Logo o schema será setado e ao executar esse update, criarei o novo schema para aquele determinado cliente,
Não posso deixar automatico, pois se terei N schema, ele não irá conseguir atualizar todos os schemas, apenas o que estiver setado como padrão/atual

Comment: Você quer chamar uma `migration` no tempo de execução do sistema?

Comment: Exatamente isso, para a criar o schema como eu mencionei ali no motivo, rsrs

Comment: Não vejo necessidade. Você pode simular o comportamento de uma `Migration` através de uma `Action`. Fica mais dentro do Design da aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Existe uma forma de executar o `migrate.exe` manualmente, em `command line`.

Por exemplo:

```
Migrate.exe MyApp.exe /startupConfigurationFile="MyApp.exe.config" /targetMigration="update-database"
```

Para criar um método que execute isso, você deve criar um processo e informar os parâmetros necessários para executar o `Migrate.exe`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
private void ExecuteMigration() 
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = "Migrate.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = @"MyApp.exe /startupConfigurationFile=\"MyApp.exe.config\" /targetMigration=\"update-database\"";
    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

Dessa forma você consegue executar o `migration` através de um método dentro do seu programa.

O `Migrate.exe` fica em `<project folder>\packages\EntityFramework.<version>\tools`

Veja mais algumas informações sobre o `Migrate.exe` no site da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx)